# Kubernetes resource type's history

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to check history of different kubernetes resource type? It can be an additional plugin.

Use case:
For example currently we have a statefulset on a 5 node cluster:

```
name: X
replica:3
resources:
 memory:
   limit: 2Gi
   request: 1Gi
```

currently replica 1 is on node_1, replica 2 is on node_2, replica 3 is on node_3.

I am curious about the state of the resources for any given time.

Let's say I want to check that one month ago what were the resource limits. How many replica we had and on which node were those allocated.

Comment: The resource limits of pods do not dynamically change. If your store your yaml in some version control system then you should be able to see what changed when and who changed it.
The information which pod ran on which node in the past sounds like telemetry data for monitoring.

Comment: The history of configuration should be in your Git repository.

Comment: Big no. How would you tell from your git that on certain day which pod ran on which node? How would you tell from your git, that after experimenting,modifying something directly how some config has been changed? How would you tell from your git that on which day was a new pod introduced/deleted(your git history has nothing to do with the actual deployment date )?

Comment: What happened when - logs is a good source for that. Resource type history - Git should be the source for that. In clusters and namespaces that you care about, only a Deploy-pipeline originating from Git should be used, no manual changes.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question - you **can't** do that using oob functionality.

You need any existing monitoring solution for Kubernetes that is capable of exposing metrics you need. What comes to my mind:

- `kube-state-metrics server` + `promethues`
- `kube-state-metrics server` + `metricbeat`

For instance `kube-state-metrics` server exposes such metric like Pod's container resource limit (`kube_pod_container_resource_limits`), and `metricbeat` digest that metrics and helps to visualize it.

**Collecting Kubernetes state metrics and events**

> A single instance is deployed to collect Kubernetes metrics. It is
> integrated with the kube-state-metrics API **to monitor state changes of
> objects managed by Kubernetes.** This is the section of the config that
> defines state_metrics collection.
> `$HOME/k8s-o11y-workshop/Metricbeat/Metricbeat.yml`:

```
kubernetes.yml: |-
  - module: kubernetes
    metricsets:
      - state_node
      - state_deployment
      - state_replicaset
      - state_pod
      - state_container
      # Uncomment this to get k8s events:
      - event
    period: 10s
    host: ${NODE_NAME}
    hosts: ["kube-state-metrics:8080"]
```